# Get boolean from savedInstancestate on orientatioin change

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation

I want to save some boolean variables in Bundle i.e savedInstaceState those i can use after orientation changed .

I tried but always the savedInstanceState result in null

```
if(savedInstanceState==null){
 savedInstanceState=new Bundle();
 savedInstanceState.putBoolean("isLogoLoaded",true);
 }else{
 savedInstanceState.putBoolean("isLogoLoaded",true);
}
```

please provide the better way thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which method are you calling that logic?

I am guessing that is in onCreate(), onCreate is where you LOAD the savedInstanceState, it is NOT where you SAVE your data. (you can also load it in onRestoreInstanceState)

You want to save your data in 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
     savedInstanceState.putBoolean("isLogoLoaded", true);
 }
```

From here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code for saving the values which you want to restore -

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("TEXT", user);

    }
```

By this you can get those values back -

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedUser = savedInstanceState.getString("TEXT");
    Log.d("enregistred value", savedUser);
```

Hope this helps :)

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("isLogoLoaded",true);
}
```

and

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
          logo = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isLogoLoaded"); 
}
```